# How some mutual funds pay such high dividends

Tags: mutual-funds, dividends, index-fund

There are some funds where the dividend yields are pretty much off the charts:
http://www.nasdaq.com/dividend-stocks/

How do these funds pay these astronomical dividends? What is the catch that is not obvious?

Comment: Sometimes, I high dividend yield means that the share price suddenly went down sharply. That doesn't mean future dividends will be at the same rate, though.

Comment: Also, stocks will sometimes give a large one time special dividend.  So the indicated dividend might be a better idea of what to expect.  Though even that is not perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at their dividend history.  The chart there is simply reporting the most recent dividend (or a recent time period, in any event).  `GF` for example: http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/gf/dividend-history

It's had basically two significant dividends and a bunch of small dividends.  Past performance is not indicative of future returns and all that.  It might never have a similar dividend again.

What you're basically looking at with that chart is a list of recently well-performing funds - funds who had a good year.  They obviously may or may not have such a good year next year.

You also have funds that are dividend-heavy (intended explicitly to return significant dividends).  Those may return large dividends, but could still fall in value significantly.  Look at [ACP](http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/acp/interactive-chart?timeframe=2y) for example: it's currently trading near it's 2-year low.  You got a nice dividend, but the price dropped quite a bit, so you lost a chunk of that money.  (I don't know if ACP is a dividend-heavy fund, but it looks like it might be.)

GF's [chart](http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/gf/interactive-chart?timeframe=1y) is also indicative of something interesting: it fell off a cliff right after it gave its dividend (at the end of the year).  Dropped $4.  I think that's because this is a mutual fund priced based on the NAV of its holdings - so it dividended some of those holdings, which dropped the share price (and the NAV of the fund) by that amount.  IE, $18 a share, $4 a share dividend, so after that $14 a share.  (The rest of the dividends are from stock holdings which pay dividends themselves, if I understand properly).  Has a similar drop in Dec 2013.  They may simply be trying to keep the price of the fund in the ~$15 a share range; I suspect (but don't know) that some funds have in their charter a requirement to stay in a particular range and dividend excess value.

Comment: Oh boy, why would some one be restricted to be in a certain range (on the upside)?

Comment: Well, it depends on the Fund, but funds that are expected to generate dividends might be required to try to keep the net asset value around a certain amount, and dividend gains above that.  Like I said, I'm not sure on that one, as I'm not really that familiar with dividend-heavy funds (as I prefer tax-friendly options!).

Comment: Thanks. In Canada, Canadian dividends are very tax friendly :)